# Spring Data Rest insert new object with OneToMany relationship result json URI error

Tags: javascript, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am working in a new project and have the following situation: I need to insert a new Company with some new Employees. In one form the user are able to register a new small Company.
Using: Spring Boot 2.0 with Spring Data REST and Hibernate (BackEnd), React (FrontEnd)

I am using the following structure:

The Entities:

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_company_address", nullable = false)
    private CompanyAddress companyAddress;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy="company")
    private List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    /* 
     * Getters and Setters
     */
}
```

```
@Entity
public class CompanyAddress {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_company_address")
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade= { CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name="id_country", nullable = false)
    private Country country;

    /* 
     * Getters and Setters
     */
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_country")
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name", length = 255)
    private String name;

    /* 
     * Getters and Setters
     */
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_company", nullable = false)
    private Company company;

    /* 
     * Getters and Setters
     */
}
```

The repositories:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "company", path = "companies", excerptProjection = CompanyProjection.class)
public interface CompanyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Company, Long> {}
```

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "employee", path = "employees", excerptProjection = EmployeeProjection.class)
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Long> {}
```

The JSON (build mannualy for test):

```
const company = {
    name: 'test',
    companyAddress: {
        country: http://localhost:8080/api/countries/1,
        street: 'Street test'
    }
    employeeList: [{
        name: 'test 01'
    },
    {
        name: 'test 02'
    }]
}
```

I'm having the following error "JSON parse error: Failed to convert from type [java.net.URI] to type [com.project.model.Employee] for value 'name';".

I understand that I should send the URI when I already have the data persisted, and the following case is an example:

```
const company = {
    name: 'test',
    employeeList: [http://localhost:8080/api/countries/1]
}
```

My problem is that the Employee isn't saved yet, I need to save the new Company with the new Employees, so I don't have the URI.

I tried to use the annotation 'exported = false' in the Employee repository (as I've seen in some forums), like the example:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "employee", path = "employees", excerptProjection = EmployeeProjection.class, exported = false)
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Long> {}
```

It worked, but I don't have acess to save/find in the Employee repository anymore. So, it doesn't work for my situation.

Is there a correct way to save the new company with a list of new employees at the same time?

Comment: what would you do if employee (test 01) already exists?

Comment: In this specific case it will always be a new employee. I was thinking in build a form to manage (create and update) the employees after this case working. This case is really to insert a new company with a some employees, without the need of create a new company and go to other place and add one by one.

Comment: My doubt is more in relation to the @OneToMany, because in future I will have some other cases that I need to use that structure, like a Sale with a List of Items or a Person with a list of Contact, both cases inserting with cascade the entity and the list of related items.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping relationship is fine. You can try this approach.

```
 @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST, path="/create")
 public String createCompany(@RequestBody Company companyJson) {

    String companyName = companyJson.getName();
    Company alreadyExistsCompany = companyRepository.findByName(companyName);

    Company company = null;

    if(alreadyExistsCompany == null){
        Company newCompany = new Company ();
        newCompany.setName(companyName);
        company = companyRepository.save(newCompany);
    } else{
        company = alreadyExistsCompany;
    }

    for (Employee employee : companyJson.getEmployeeList()){
        employee.setCompany (company);
        employeeRepository.save (employee);
    }

    return "done";
}
```

You json request should be like this:

```
{
  "name": "test company 02",
  "employeeList": [
    { "name": "employee 01"},
    { "name": "employee 02"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: With this case I have a problem in conversion using URI. I didn't show my full Company entity because thought was no need, but Company has an One To One relationship with CompanyAddress and the CompanyAddress has a Many to One with Country. In Json I receive the country as a URI, and it is resulting the following error: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/countries/1').

Comment: I just edit my question using the JSON with the companyAddress and the country URI.

Comment: @RobsonFarias - Could you also update your Company class too?

Comment: Of course! I edited with the entities CompanyAddress and Country too, maybe it helps. I'm really confused what I'm doing wrong that the Repository can't receive a list with new objects, it's a situation that I believe will happen a lot in future, including a new object with many lists.

Comment: @RobsonFarias - best way would be by moving step by step. I can try a better way but wanted to know if you can have different structure of json request?

Comment: I am asking as your structure is wrong .country: http://localhost:8080/api/employees/1, how you will know in request its 1 id for employee with id  1?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it was supposed to be: localhost:8080/api/countries/1. I'm editing to post here the entities in English, since we are developing in other language (not my decision). So, in some aspects, it can result in some errors changing to English.

Comment: where the street in your entity?

Comment: Edited in the question. Just add a String street, it is redundant for the problem. You can also remove from json the street name, I use just as an example that the object contains other attributes. It will have number, complement and etc... I'm not adding this information because I believe been redundant. The core problem resides in the relationships.